# Firebase push function is not working with sails post method

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sails.js

When I am hitting this function directly by URL it worked and this insert data in Firebase object

```
addCountry: function (req, res) {
        var ref = db.ref();
        var usersRef = ref.child("country");
        usersRef.push({
          name: 'United States',
          is_deleted: 0,
        });
        return res.view('city-listing'); 
}
```

But when I called this function by the form submit post method then it will throw the error: 
"error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
 Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Error occurs if you are sending the view more than once in the same route handler . It had happened to me once too. Check that you don't have more than one view related rendering which might execute twice.